# Error on new XNA 4.0 game project - No suitable graphics card found

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Any ideas on how to fix this? According to what I remember about XNA 3 was that when running the application from scratch, I would get a blue colored windows with nothing rendered.

Any suggestions?

[image]

**EDIT!**

I right clicked the project and selected Properties and changed the Game Profile from **Use HiDef** to **Use Reach**. Now the familiar blue tint window is showing as expected.
[image]

What am I losing if I choose the limited API and why did I even have to choose this for it to work?

Comment: As a sidenote, I wonder why they chose to call it "Reach"... I just got done playing some Halo: Reach so that came to mind immediately. But I suspect it's more because of the symbolism of "reaching" more devices?

Comment: Sorrry,but i dont know where are these project properies. Could someone tell me?

Comment: @Romantyk12 - http://i56.tinypic.com/2iqeu6t.png Hopefully this image helps. After clicking properties on the right-click pop up, the first tab labelled 'XNA Game Studio' has settings near the top to choose Reach or HiDef profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your follow up question:

> What am I losing if I choose the limited API?

[This blog post explains the differences between Reach and HiDef](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310004334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx). In a nutshell, the Reach profile does not allow the use of some of the more advanced graphics card features. But it runs on more hardware.

Comment: after changing properties to reach same error is appearing

Comment: @maryam It's possible that your graphics card does not support the requirements of even the `Reach` profile, which requires at least Shader Model 2.0, and a few other features which should be common on GPUs of that era - see the table linked in my answer for details. (Unless the error message itself still says "HiDef profile" - then you've not changed the setting correctly / for the correct project.)

Answer (score 2):

XNA Framework HiDef profile requires a DX10 capable video card.

If you have a DX10 capable card, make sure your latest display drivers are installed.

If you don't have a DX10 capable card go into project properties and change the profile from HiDef to Reach.

Edit: I see you answered your own question, but to answer your question about what you will be missing:

Probably antything related to DX10. I can't remember the exact differences in my head, but lighting and particle effects are two areas where DX10 excels over DX9.

Comment: It needs a card that had most of the capabilities that a DX10 card has, but it still runs on DX9.

Comment: Between DX9c and DX10 there are increases to the max texture size,  increases to the maximum # of texture references, increases on the number of shader commands to name a few.